# Add 0's in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
DECLARE @MilestoneName VARCHAR( 50 );
SELECT @MilestoneName = 'Milsetone' + CAST( 001 AS VARCHAR );
```

This gives me the result `Milestone1`

But I want to the result to be `Milestone001`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If `001` is literal then why not this `Milsetone001'

Comment: I think it's an int possibly from a column, he just wanted to simplify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
DECLARE @MilestoneName VARCHAR( 50 )
SELECT @MilestoneName = 'Milestone' + RIGHT('000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,001),3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @MilestoneName = 'Milestone' + RIGHT( 1000 + 001, 3 );
```